# Bluetooth keyboard connected but cannot be used in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, wireless-keyboards

I've updated Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, I've tried connected my bluetooth keyboard and it is **paired**, somehow i cannot type anything with bluetooth keyboard

FYI, it is working fine with ubuntu 20.04 and in windows or mac os. I don't have any other bluetooth keybaord so I cannot test further.

is there something that i can do to solve this ?

[image: my bluetooth connection]

Comment: @guiverc thankyou for reminding me, it's my fault to wrote it 21.04, i mean 20.04 LTS. Question edited

Comment: Hi, do you get answer to your question?

Comment: @ArmenGrigoryan good news is in 22.10 it's working fine without any problem

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Ubuntu 22.04, connected Bluetooth keyboard. After upgrading Bluetooth monitor driver to 5.66, still doesn't work.

Using  `sudo bluetoothctl` then it works.